# Nero ask to save an image file

Tags: software-rec, burning, compact-disc, nero, cd-burning

Whenever i burn a CD with Nero Burning ROM / Nero express, as soon as i click "Burn" the save dialog box opens that prompt me to save the project as an image file.

Plus if i burn the CD, the CD is not actually burning.

Why is this happening? Let me know  if any input is needed. Thanks!

Comment: There should be a tick box that says, don't ask me again for the save project. Not sure about the other problem, sounds like it is doing a test burn.

Answer (score 0):

Burn to iso image may be set as your "default" burn method. In your preferences you may be able to change that by picking your CD/DVD-R drive instead.